# Handle multiple user sessions using AuthComponent in CakePHP

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I am using CakePHP 2.4. I am using AuthComponent.

There is an User Management module in Admin Panel, where I am showing list of users. I have given a link `Login as User` corresponds to each user.

Now I have to handle multiple user sessions on the basis of `user_type` field in a way that an Admin & the specific user sessions can maintain in the same browser.

There are 3 user_types in `users` table: `admin`,`dealer` and `general`.

Please suggest, If `AuthComponent` have this feature. Any other alternate solution would also be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want three different sessions at the same time or the ability to work as any of the three different user types at any moment? The first is probably impossible with sessions, the second is as simple as setting an appropriate value at the session (i.e. `works_as_user_type = admin`).

Comment: Yes, the three user sessions differentiated by user_type have to be saved as this is also possible in core php. I am asking if there is any method to implement it using AuthComponent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly what you want... If you can do it for one user type you can do it for any. You just need to figure out a way to change it, which could be a simple method like `UsersController::changeUserTypeTo($user_type)` to set the appropriate session values.

Comment: @Arun Jain : Its been 2 years. Have you found any solution for this issue. Your answer will be very much helpful for me. I am facing the same problem.